# Custom watch face for Android Wear

Tags: android, wear-os

A few apps have come out already for Android Wear that contain custom watch faces ([like this one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bytemesoftware.wear.faces.binary)). They are not just apps that simply display a watch face; they are full-fledged faces that are selectable when long-pressing the home screen of the watch. I can't find any documentation on how to set up your app to provide a custom face. How do you configure your app to provide a face?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**EDIT** *With the update of Android Wear to Lollipop, there is a brand-new (and more importantly, **official**) API for Android Wear Watch Faces.*

You can check the [blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/12/watch-face-api-now-available-for.html) on the subject, read the [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/watch-faces/index.html) or [download the sample code](http://developer.android.com/samples/WatchFace/project.html).

Everything below this line is for historical purposes only :)

---

You just need to provide an Activity with a specific intent-filter, and include a couple of permissions (information from [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/297r7m/watch_face_development_on_android_wear/)).

Activity:

```
<activity
    android:name=".WatchActivity"
    android:allowEmbedded="true"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar"
    android:label="@string/watch_preview_name">

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.clockwork.home.preview"
        android:resource="@drawable/watch_preview_image" />

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="com.google.android.clockwork.home.category.HOME_BACKGROUND" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

And the permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.permission.PROVIDE_BACKGROUND" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

By the way, the source code from the app you mentioned from the Play Store is also [availabe on github](https://github.com/dwa012/WearBinaryWatchFace/).

---

The reason for including the WAKE_LOCK permission is very well explained in [this G+ post by Sam Duke](https://plus.google.com/+SamDuke474/posts/P5Ajfzj6NWt). Basically, when the watch is dimmed the CPU goes into a low power state, so that updates to the watch face display aren't shown immediately. Acquiring a PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK whenever the screen needs to be updated solves this problem.

---

**EDIT** *Note that this is an "unofficial" API, and as per [this post by Wayne Piekarski](https://plus.google.com/+WaynePiekarski/posts/2bzJJxG2CAX), it may break in the future when the official API is released (which should happen when Android Wear is upgraded to L).*

Comment: Ah, there it is. What are the permissions for? It seems to work on a Wear emulator without them, and `WAKE_LOCK` especially seems unneeded.

Comment: Also curious about WAKE_LOCK

Comment: wake lock is required. I made a post on G+ community about it

Comment: @Sam Can you elaborate on _why_ it's required? And do you have a link to the post?

Comment: @Jarett sure. here's the post: https://plus.google.com/112368135370463751319/posts/P5Ajfzj6NWt

Happy to write that up or copy paste into this answer.

Comment: @Sam That's very clever. Would you mind if I incorporated that point into the answer? (With attribution, of course)

Comment: of course, just keep a link to the original post in there if you can. hopefully it will help people and maybe hit a few of the watchface templates out there too

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT**: *Below is a new blog post of mine that explains the new Watch Face API in Lollipop.*

http://toastdroid.com/2014/12/10/developing-a-watch-face-for-android-wear-lollipop/

---

I wrote a blog post describing the process of developing a watchface.

http://toastdroid.com/2014/07/18/developing-watchfaces-for-android-wear/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create watch faces using OpenGL ES then our experience in creating one will be useful for you:

http://androidworks-kea.blogspot.com/2015/02/developers-notes-v-custom-watch-faces.html